# delete record in restapi

Tags: rest-api

I am using 2 different salesforce accounts (say source & destination).I source I have webservice method which has @Httpdelete.
i.e

```
@HTTPDelete 
 webservice static void DeleteAccounts()  
 {
    List<Account> accList=[select Id from account where Name LIKE :'%someName%'];
    Database.delete(accList);
 }
```

In destination I have the code as follows:

```
 Http h = new Http(); 
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setMethod('DELETE');
 req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer +Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);
 req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');
 req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest');  
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req); // JSON string is generated at this point
      system.debug('---res.getBody()--'+res.getBody());
```

Now I am getting the ID(assume single record). But I dont understand how to proceed further to delete the record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find the code from [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm) for deleting an account.

```
@HttpDelete
global static void doDelete() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    delete account;
}
```

You need to get the particular account ID in source to be deleted as below.

**String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);**

Now in destination set the endpoint appending the account ID `req.setEndpoint('https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/accountId');`

and set the method as delete.

```
req.setMethod('DELETE');
```

You can also pass the id for the record to be deleted by appending in the end of the request url

`?accountId=XXXXXXXXXXXXX.`

Get the Id in Source by using `RestContext` and do the delete as above.

```
RestContext.request.params.get('accountId')
```

Comment: Thanks saroj & tugce sirin, u made my day. its working. thanks once again to both of u.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use HttpPost to send parameter or add id of spesified record to url.

Example 1

```
 @HTTPPost 
     webservice static void DeleteAccounts(String someId)  
     {
        List<Account> accList=[select Id from account where Id = :someId];
        Database.delete(accList);
     }
```

In destination:

```
Http h = new Http(); 
 HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
 req.setMethod('DELETE');
 req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer +Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);
 req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');
 req.setBody('someId');
 req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest');  
      HttpResponse res = h.send(req); // JSON string is generated at this point
      system.debug('---res.getBody()--'+res.getBody());
```

Example 2:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/AccountRest/*')
global with sharing class AccountRest {

    @HttpDelete
    global static void DeleteAccounts() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String accountId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        Account account = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        delete account;
    }

}
```

In destination:

```
Http h = new Http(); 
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
     req.setMethod('DELETE');
     req.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer +Helper.GetAccessToken().access_token);
     req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=UTF-8');
     req.setEndpoint('https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/AccountRest/YOURID');  
          HttpResponse res = h.send(req); // JSON string is generated at this point
          system.debug('---res.getBody()--'+res.getBody());
```

Comment: @HttpDelete methods do not support parameters

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You need http post or you need to add id of spesified record to end of the url. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I passed ID in the setEndpoint method and used the same code as yours but still delete not working. am I missing anything?